# Using RTC to disable profile on server?

Tags: c#, voip, sip

I have problem with Profile roaming in RTC. so let me describe my program to understand it better.

I write Soft-Phone base on sip Protocol, for using Sip I decide using RTC Library for Communication. This Soft-Phone do these features perfectly like hold, redirect, answer, hangup and etc. I use C# and `Interop.RTCCORELib dll` for RTC. after too many time using this phone with any type of PBX server like (asterisk, asterisk windows and Elestisk) I face mysterious problem in my Soft-Phone.

**Problem:**
when operator login and using phone I create `IRTCProfile2 Propety` to register this Profile on server. after operator don his/her work with phone, oprator close phone. In this moment I run method to disable profile on server. I checked profile, and profile state changed to "Unregistered". **But the sip user still login on server**. I check msdn and find this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In this article describe how to disable profile on server. and I do this same. here's My Code:

```
  public void unregisterProfile()
    {
        if (_rtcProvisioning.Profiles.Count > 0 && 
           ((IRTCProfile)_rtcProvisioning.Profiles[1]).State == RTC_REGISTRATION_STATE.RTCRS_REGISTERED)
        {
            _rtcProvisioning.DisableProfile(_rtcProfile);
            _rtcPresence.DisablePresence();
            _rtcClient.PrepareForShutdown();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _rtcClient.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Also in this article say call `IRTCClientPresence2.DisablePresence` method.

> So any solution? any tips? did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you missed  [IRTCClientPresence2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775486(v=vs.85).aspx) which has the actual [DisablePresence()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775490(v=vs.85).aspx) call.

From the docs;

> The IRTCClientPresence2 interface derives from the IRTCClientPresence
>   interface. It adds roaming and grouping capabilities for presence
>   objects to the client. This interface can be obtained by calling
>   QueryInterface on the IRTCClientPresence interface.

Edit: You're also calling RTCClient::Shutdown() immediately after calling DisableProfile (and DisablePresence when that is added), [the documentation for ShutDown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775587(v=vs.85).aspx) states though;

> To give the SIP stack a chance to gracefully unregister from
>   registrars and unsubscribe Watchers, the Client should call the
>   asynchronous method PrepareForShutdown before calling Shutdown.

Comment: @Rev Are you sure the actual call to `_rtcProvisioning.DisableProfile(_rtcProfile);` is done?

Comment: @Rev It's been a while since I did COM interop so my array mapping may be off, but is Profiles[1] really the correct element to check the status on, not Profiles[0] if Count is > 0?

Comment: First yes, cuz `_rtcProfile state` change after this line , Second: I think so. profiles[1] use only in if condition and `_rtcProfile` is same object registered on server and this object goes for disable method.

Comment: @Rev Added some extra info to the answer.

Comment: @Rev Not sure why you un-upvoted without a comment on why the PrepareForShutdown information was not helpful. It solves exactly the problem you're stating that you're having.

Comment: Cuz I want run bounty and create same Conditions for all(whom answer  to question). In that way your are only person helped me. Thanks, but I still have this problem!

Comment: @Rev Did you implement the PrepareForShutdown solution? If so, could you post the code? I tested it, works for me to get it to sign out.